# Delphi FMX StringGrid how to change the keyboardtype to numeric

Tags: android, delphi, keyboard, firemonkey, stringgrid

Using Delphi 11.1 FireMonkey
Hello I would like to change the keyboardtype of a stringgrid column to mumeric (for Android).
Could someone please help me with that?
Thanks! Ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDE or Runtime ?

- IDE use another column type
- Runtime if you create the column then create it as a TIntegerColumn, TcurrencyColumn or TFloatColumn (depending of "mumeric" ;-) means for you) and not a simple TColumn (default is TStringColumn).

By the way, if somebody knows the way to change a TColumn to a specific type at runtime I should appreciate the tip